# newtx font makes arrows bigger in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, newtxmath, newtx

I noticed that the newtx font somehow makes the arrows in tikz-cd diagrams appear significantly bigger.
I wonder why that is and if there would be any way to solve this issue.

MWE below.

The code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
X_0 \rar & X_1 \lar[shift left=1.5] \lar[shift right=1.5] \rar[shift right=1.5] \rar[shift left=1.5] & X_2 \lar\lar[shift right=3]\lar[shift left=3] \rar \rar[shift left=3] \rar[shift right=3] & \dots \lar[shift left=1.5]\lar[shift left=4.5]\lar[shift right=1.5]\lar[shift right=4.5]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

yields the following picture :

[image: normal arrows]

but uncommenting the newtxtext and math will give me this :

[image: BIG arrows with newtx font]

Comment: Arrows in the `newtxmath` font are bigger, that's the main reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem has been solved with the comment.

Comment: @ged it would be better to post your edit as a self-answer to the question (in the Answer box) and remove it from the question text.

Comment: @all I voted to reopen to allow a self-answer to be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick way to fix it by simply changing my arrow tips (allowing me to also match the arrow style of the newtx font). By simply adding

```
\tikzset{>={Straight Barb[scale = 0.7]}}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz}
```

to my preamble I get this :

[image: quick fix]

which already looks much nicer. I still wonder what causes the problem in the first place and would appreciate any insight.

It is in general better to make these changes local since they may affect other `tikzpicture`s if they are not.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\tikzcdset{smaller arrows/.style={arrow style=tikz,every arrow/.append style={>={Straight Barb[scale = 0.7]}}}}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[smaller arrows]
X_0 \rar & X_1 \lar[shift left=1.5] \lar[shift right=1.5] \rar[shift right=1.5] \rar[shift left=1.5] & X_2 \lar\lar[shift right=3]\lar[shift left=3] \rar \rar[shift left=3] \rar[shift right=3] & \dots \lar[shift left=1.5]\lar[shift left=4.5]\lar[shift right=1.5]\lar[shift right=4.5]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can accept own answer and by this inform us, that your problem is solved!